# Dicom error after trying to perform a DICOM ping

Tags: ping, dicom

I have made a simple program that is supposed to perform a DICOM ping to the server.
it is giving the following error:

> reject - result: REJECTED_PERMANENT source: DICOM_UL_SERVICE_USER reason: NO_REASON_GIVEN

For the server I am using JDiCom to run the RIS Server and I also tried using the AW Server, which gave me this error.
I am very new to this and this is my first program so i dont have a lot of details regarding the different parameters.

I am not able to understand the reason for such an error as all the details added to perform the ping are correct, like the port number, ip address and the ae title.
my system is also configured on the server, so even that is not the issue.

is there something i am missing?

Comment: Are you using any DICOM toolkit to develop your application? In that case, which toolkit? Which DICOM server are you running? Are the firewalls configured to allow traffic over the relevant port(s)? What happens if you place a server on the same system as your client application?

Comment: BTW, instead of responding with a comment, please edit your question.

Comment: i hope i could clear the picture for you a little bit

Answer (score 0):

When there is a permanent rejection such as this when negotiating a DICOM association, it is probably due to mismatch in the configured AE Titles or a mismatch with the SOP Classes supported between the client and server.  I would suggest you investigate that the Called AE Title configured on your client matches the AE title of the server.  I would also confirm the sop classes you're proposing match the SOP Classes supported by the server.